# Man awakes in space around other people and wakes them up early, involves spider-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

This book started with a man who wakes, spinning in space, surrounded by other
bodies that are slowly spinning. He does something that awakens them all early, 
somehow ends up on a planet. Somewhere along the story spider-like aliens attach to their brains.

It's been over 40 years since I read it. I believe it is a series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [guide to writing a good question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if it triggers any more details you can add to your question.

Comment: Do you recall a lot of famous historical figures (including the man who wakes at the beginning) as characters?

Comment: Were the bodies in a ship that was in space, or were they literally in space? If the former, was the whole ship spinning, or were the bodies spinning independently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all you may have looked at this question and gave it some thought.  I was able to 
find the book.  It is called, *To Your Scattered Bodies Go*, by Philip Jose Farmer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Even though it's to your own question, this would be a better answer if you include some detail as to how this novel matches the question.

Comment: Aha!  @Spencer had the right idea!  I was sidetracked by "spinning _in space_" which had me picturing a starlight black void, instead of stacks of bodies spinning between vertical rails...

Comment: Yes, once i found the book I realized it would have been more clear if I would have said, slowly spinning just above the ground of an unknown planet/place. Also would have been helpful if I would have mentioned the river! But it had been 40 years since reading it.